# Converting to executable using pyinstaller having tensorflow model embeded but prediction and predicted image not showing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm working on a task that takes image from user then predict the result of the image. The code is shown below. its a working sample of the full task

```
import sys, os

import shap

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)



class CastingProductDetector(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.model = tf.keras.models.load_model(resource_path("asset/casting_product_detection_model.hdf5"))

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.select_image_button = tk.Button(self, text="Select Image", command=self.select_image)
        self.select_image_button.pack(side="top")

        self.image_label = tk.Label(self)
        self.image_label.pack(side="top")

        self.detect_button = tk.Button(self, text="Detect", command=self.detect)
        self.detect_button.pack(side="top")

        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit_button.pack(side="bottom")

        self.predicted_label = tk.Label(self)
        self.predicted_label.pack(side="top")

    def select_image(self):
        self.file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        if self.file_path:
            self.image = Image.open(self.file_path)
            self.image = self.image.resize((300, 300))
            self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
            self.image_label.config(image=self.photo)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "No image selected.")

    def detect(self):
        my_data_dir = resource_path('')
        train_path = my_data_dir + 'train/'
        print(train_path)
        image_shape = (300, 300, 1)
        data_dir = resource_path('')
        train_cases = [i for i in os.listdir(f'{data_dir}train/')]
        train_sample = [cv2.imread(train_path + i, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).reshape(1, *image_shape) / 255 for i in
                        np.random.choice(train_cases, 20, replace=False)]
        explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(self.model, train_sample[0])

        try:
            img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(self.image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            img1 = cv2.imread(self.file_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).reshape(1, *image_shape)
            shap_values = explainer.shap_values(img1)
            shap.image_plot(shap_values, img1, show=False)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (300, 300))
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)
            img = img / 255.0
            img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
            prediction = self.model.predict(img)
            plt.axis('off')
            # Create a Matplotlib figure canvas in the Tkinter window
            fig1 = plt.gcf()
            fig1.set_size_inches(5.3, 3.4)
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(plt.gcf(), master=self.master)
            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top")
        except AttributeError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "No image selected.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = CastingProductDetector(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Also the following pyintaller code was use:

```
python -m  PyInstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed  --add-data "C:/___/DIsk Prediction/asset;asset/"  --add-data "C:/___/DIsk Prediction/train;train/" "C:/___/DIsk Prediction/testing.py"
```

The model (hdf5) is inside the asset directory.
But after the process has finish the excutable file could run but the prediction non the predicted image was not displaying. 'My suggestion' is that the tensorflow model is not working after using --onefile command but I want to use --onefile due to the size of the application.

How can I resolve this issue such that the prediction and predicted image could display or what I'm not doing right or recommendations

Comment: See [mre]. Provide enough debugging information. Did you try "--log-level" or "--debug" options?